# what is the difference between instagram short post link and long post link

Tags: instagram

what is the difference betwen instagram short link and long link like

short link ---->  https://www.instagram.com/p//BLgg-slBL1_/
and 
long link  ---->  https://www.instagram.com/p/BLgjfOFB7ENbNvlspNi1LUTCQ8n1pIz2FQgi5k0/

Comment: both of those links are broken...

Comment: i know they are broken but why one is long and other is short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long one is from a private profile, only people who follow that user will be able to view the post.

short one is from public profile, anyone can view it.